# Do I need SVN to download this project?

Tags: android, svn, version-control, versioning

Android newbie here and would like to create a basic app using the [AndriodPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Quickstart) library.

The instructions to download are:

```
svn checkout https://androidplot.jira.com/svn/ANDROIDPLOT/  
trunk/Examples/Quickstart Quickstart
```

Is there a way to download without SVN so I can get started?

If not, what SVN and how do I use it?

I assume it is some sort of version vcontrol but after Google-ing SVN, I am getting a lot of different answers and it is not clear what I am suppose to do...

Any point in the right direction to download this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: SVN = [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) Install a subversion client - and execute your command above (which should be all on one line) from the command line.  There are also GUI svn clients, like TortoiseSVN for Windows or Versions for MacOS.

Comment: Version control can be very useful, even for a sole developer, you should consider using it for other projects too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need SVN to download this project.

What is ment by SVN is Subversion.

Depending on the platform you are using, you have to install a Subversion client. Under linux distributions, just search for the subversion in repository.

Under Windows and Mac OS X you'll find a graphical client, that will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could download all the files manually or work on individual files e.g. https://androidplot.jira.com/svn/ANDROIDPLOT/trunk/Examples/Quickstart/src/com/example/MainActivity.java

but it's gonna be easier to just install svn and then checkout the repository and get a copy of the files on your machine.

Red bean did a good intro and guide when I was learning it http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch01.html

And PS. learn GIT (better and now widely used)